# Calling a function when a <div> is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I'm working on a web page that is supposed to have a block of text that changes from "Click Me" to "Ouch!" when the user clicks anywhere inside the block. I'm having trouble making the text change when I click inside the  that I've created.

Here is my html file which also includes some CSS and Javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exam 1 Tanner Taylor</title>
        <h1>Exam 1 Tanner Taylor</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #clickMe {
                background-color: blue;
                border: 2px double black;
                font-size: larger;
            }
        </style>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function clickMe() {
                var TTclick = document.getElementById("clickMe");
            return TTclick;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="clickMe" onclick="clickMe()">
        <p>
            Click Me
        </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As this is written the block is displayed properly as far as background color, border, and original text, however when I click inside the block nothing happens. I have checked the debugger on my browser, but I'm not getting any errors. I'm thinking I'm either not making the  element clickable, or the clickMe() function isn't being called properly how I have it written in the  section.

Anybody willing to point me in the right direction?

### Demo:

```js
function clickMe() {
  var TTclick = document.getElementById("clickMe");
  return TTclick;
}
```

```css
#clickMe {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px double black;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe" onclick="clickMe()">
  <p>
    Click Me
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: A `div` element has no `.value` property. That's for form inputs.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set the value of the div, but what you want to do is set its innerhtml.

```
function clickMe() {
            document.getElementById("clickMe").innerHTML = "Ouch!";
        }
```

No need to set variables or return them.  Also, I would lose the paragraph tag inside your clickMe div.

Comment: Dang, I knew that. Still trying to keep everything straight on what goes with which elements. Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, clicking outside the text, does not register as clicking on the DOM element.

Either remove the paragraph tag inside the div and keep the text, or add this CSS:

```css
div#clickMe > p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Below, you will find a simple demo.

```js
function clickMe() {
  toggle("div#clickMe>p", "Click Me", "Ouch!");
}

function toggle(selector, defaultText, alternateText) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector);
  var text = element.innerHTML
  element.innerHTML = text == defaultText ? alternateText : defaultText;
}
```

```css
div#clickMe {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px double black;
  font-size: larger;
}

div#clickMe>p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="clickMe" onclick="clickMe()">
  <p>
    Click Me
  </p>
</div>
```